# How I can typecast the "0.0001 EOS" into eosio::asset

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, eosio.token

I declared a variable `value = "0.0001 EOS";` , inside my action I want to transfer those asset to a account .I am having difficulty to typacasting this string into the eosio::asset value .
my code goes like this :

```
...
std::string value = "0.0001 EOS";
eosio::asset tosend = (eosio::asset)value;
...
```

it gives me error

```
 error: no matching conversion for C-style cast from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to
     'eosio::asset'
           eosio::asset tosend = (eosio::asset)value;
```

if I pass the tosend value from cleos command it would work fine .
so my question is can I typcast the string value into eosio::token ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the way to solve this problem .I use the function of `symbol.hpp` which is located at `eosiolib/symbol.hpp` inside our eos .
First of all I create a string and then assign some amount to the struct . 
My code goes like this

```
...
std::string sym = "EOS";
symbol_type symbolvalue = string_to_symbol(4,sym.c_str());
eosio::asset tosend;
tosend.amount = 10001;
tosend.symbol = symbolvalue;
print("tosend value is ______",tosend);
...
```

so the amount here is 1.0001 EOS.
it works for me .
If anybody have better approach please feel free to share .